# How do I map this result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mapping

This isn't an exam question or anything, I'm working on a personal project but having real brain fog on this problem. I'm hoping to get some help from the community :)

I have an array...

```
const result1 = [
{ "time":"17 : 30","bays":[{"number":"bay-3","availability":false},{"number":"bay-2","availability":false},{"number":"bay-1","availability":false}]},

{"time":"18 : 00","bays":[{"number":"bay-3","availability":false},{"number":"bay-2","availability":false},{"number":"bay-1","availability":false}]},

{"time":"18 : 30","bays":[{"number":"bay-3","availability":false},{"number":"bay-2","availability":false},{"number":"bay-1","availability":false}]}];
```

But how can I map the data from result1 to result2 in a clean esnext way?

```
const result2 = [
{ "number":"bay-1”,”times”:[{“time":"17 : 30","availability":false},{"time":"18 : 00","availability":false},{"time":"18 : 30","availability":false}]},

{"number":"bay-2”,”times”:[{“time":"17 : 30","availability":false},{"time":"18 : 00","availability":false},{"time":"18 : 30","availability":false}]},

{"number":"bay-3””,”times”:[{“time":"17 : 30","availability":false},{"time":"18 : 00","availability":false},{"time":"18 : 30","availability":false}]}];
```

Comment: It seems your result2 is not correct. Could you update it?

Comment: @Sal I posted my solution which does what you are looking for. Please take a look when you have a chance.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell that's amazing, thanks so much

Comment: @Sal Thanks, would you consider accepting my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, we'll first want to create a new array of the new values we'll be organizing by, in this case, the `number` property. We can do this by retrieving the length of the `bays` property from one of the nested objects `Array(result1[0].bays.length).fill().map()`. An even simpler way to do this would be to just `map()` over that same `bays` property like this: `result1[0].bays.map()`.

After this, we can rebuild the object in the format you need for `result2` and have those new objects mapped back to the new array we are creating. To add the `number` property, we can simply add it to the return object like this `{number}` and for the new `times` property, we'll need to iterate over the original `result1` array using `map()` and and retrieve the matching object under the `bays` property that has a `number` property value matching the one we are iterating over in our top-level array. For this, we'll only want to keep the `availability` property since we are already setting the time property in the upper-level object.

```js
result1[0].bays.map(({number}) => ({number, times: result1.map(({time, bays}) => ({time, availability: bays.find(bay => bay.number === number).availability})) }))
```

Finally, we'll just need to sort the returned object so that `result1` is sorted by bay number, numerically. This will give you your desired result:

```js
result1[0].bays.map(({number}) => ({number, times: result1.map(({time, bays}) => ({time, availability: bays.find(bay => bay.number === number).availability})) }))
  .sort((a,b) => a.number.split('-').reverse()[0] - b.number.split('-').reverse()[0])

/* -> [
        {
          number: "bay-1",
          times: [
            { time: "17 : 30", availability: false },
            { time: "18 : 00", availability: false },
            { time: "18 : 30", availability: false }
          ]
        },
        {
          number: "bay-2",
          times: [
            { time: "17 : 30", availability: false },
            { time: "18 : 00", availability: false },
            { time: "18 : 30", availability: false }
          ]
        },
        {
          number: "bay-3",
          times: [
            { time: "17 : 30", availability: false },
            { time: "18 : 00", availability: false },
            { time: "18 : 30", availability: false }
          ]
        }
      ]
*/
```

We can also create a function that performs this same computation on your array(s) and returns a new array arranged by the `number` property:

```js
const result1 = [
    { time: "17 : 30", bays: [{ number: "bay-3", availability: false }, { number: "bay-2", availability: false }, { number: "bay-1", availability: false }] },
    { time: "18 : 00", bays: [{ number: "bay-3", availability: false }, { number: "bay-2", availability: false }, { number: "bay-1", availability: false }] },
    { time: "18 : 30", bays: [{ number: "bay-3", availability: false }, { number: "bay-2", availability: false }, { number: "bay-1", availability: false }] }
];

const organizeByNumber = arr => arr[0].bays.map(({number}) => ({number, times: arr.map(({time, bays}) => ({time, availability: bays.find(bay => bay.number === number).availability})) })).sort((a,b) => a.number.split('-').reverse()[0] - b.number.split('-').reverse()[0]);

const result2 = organizeByNumber(result1);

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reduce your array to an Object keyed to the bay numbers, then convert back to a list.

```js
const result1 = [
    {
        "time": "17 : 30",
        "bays": [
            {"number": "bay-10", "availability": false},
            {"number": "bay-2", "availability": false},
            {"number": "bay-1", "availability": false}
        ]
    },

    {
        "time": "18 : 00",
        "bays": [
            {"number": "bay-10", "availability": false},
            {"number": "bay-2", "availability": true},
            {"number": "bay-1", "availability": false}
        ]
    },

    {
        "time": "18 : 30",
        "bays": [
            {"number": "bay-10", "availability": true},
            {"number": "bay-2", "availability": false},
            {"number": "bay-1", "availability": false}
        ]
    }];

const result2 = Object.entries(
    result1.reduce((acc, {bays, time}) => {
            bays.forEach(({number, availability}) => {
                acc[number] = (acc[number] || []).concat({
                    "availability": availability,
                    "time": time
                });
            });
            return acc;
        }, {}
    ))
    .reduce((acc, [bayNumber, times]) => {
        return acc.concat({"number": bayNumber, "times": times});
    }, [])
    .sort((a, b) => a.number.localeCompare(b.number, undefined,
        {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'}));

console.log(result2);
```

*I changed some values in `result1` to confirm that numeric sorting of bays is correct, and that availability is appropriately mapped as the original sample had `false` for all bays and times.